# How to change the color of an uneven surface to white in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I want to change the color of the surface of a sofa like this
[image: dark colored sofa]

to white without losing the uneven surface and wrinkles. How should I do that using Photoshop?

Comment: Hi hamid, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another option is to drop the saturation to 0 using <kbd>Image > Adjustments > Hue/Saturation...</kbd>.

Next fiddle with the levels until you're satisfied ( <kbd>Image > Adjustments > Levels...</kbd> ). Some elaboration from Joonas' comment: First move the gray arrow as far to the left as you can without washing out all the blacks (It will do most of the work). Then move the white arrow to the left as far as you can without burning it.

[image: Photoshop levels editor]

This might cause the shadows to be a bit more washed out than you prefer, but you could use the **Burn Tool** to manually add back in some contrast.

[image: Finished white couch]

Comment: The only thing I would add is actual instructions on how to adjust the levels, because it's very subjective to the photo: First move the gray arrow as far to the left as  you can without washing out all the blacks ( It will do most of the work ). Then move the white arrow to the left as far as you can without burning it.

Comment: In my opinion the grey arrow could be way more to the left side, of course that depends on the whole picture and how it fits to it. Also, I removed my answer cause it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try a `Gradient Map`:

- Be sure to have the layer selected where your sofa is on;
- Open your `Layers` palette (<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Window > Layers</kbd>);
- <kbd>Click</kbd> the white/black disc icon on the palette's bottom to open the 'Create new fill or adjustment layer` menu;
- Choose <kbd>Gradient Map</kbd>;
- Edit the gradient that appears in a nearby panel to a white to black one;
- Fiddle with the location of the stops (or add some) to achieve the desired result.

Comment: On that menu I just have gradient and not gradient map.What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using CS6, but I believe CS3 had that function as well. You could try `Layer > New Adjustment Layer > Gradient Map...` or just do it destructively through `Image > Adjustments > Gradient Map...`.